How to get hover folder icon in nautilus file manager
I want something to happen to the folder icon when I hover over it with my mouse, like changing the color of the folder title or adding an effect to the icon. How can I achieve that?
ubuntu 22.04
nautilus 42.6
enter image description here

You can't change the icon on hover, but you can apply CSS effects on hover.

Yes I want to apply CSS effects on hover

I couldn't find this in the gtk.css file, nor could I find it in the Nautilus section.
Is there a theme with this feature that I can try?

Hi everyone any help
